# How can I get a session to execute transactions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-spanner

I have something like this:

```
client = spanner.Client()
instance = client.instance(instance_id)
database = instance.database(database_id)

with database.session().transaction() as transaction:
    transaction.insert(
        table="list",
        columns=("userid", "code", "starttime"),
        values=[(id, token, datetime.utcnow())]
    )
```

The problem is
database.session().transaction()..
That does not work.
database.session() does not create a session...
How can I get the session from database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Spanner python client](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/python#write-data-with-mutations) usage guide .

The python client will use one of the sessions from the configured session pool under the hood. Session Pool can be configured using this [guide](https://googleapis.dev/python/spanner/latest/advanced-session-pool-topics.html)

Comment: can you give an exampe? for making a session pool that solves the problem... The usage guide is not clear to me.

Comment: I have added the additional info for configuring session pool in my response above. Here is the [link](https://googleapis.dev/python/spanner/latest/advanced-session-pool-topics.html) to the guide

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet:

```
spanner_client = spanner.Client()
instance = spanner_client.instance(instance_id)
database = instance.database(database_id)

with database.batch() as batch:
    batch.insert(
        table="list",
        columns=("userid", "code", "starttime"),
        values=[(id, token, datetime.utcnow())
        ],
    )
```